# mysql error: use result of innerjoin into new query

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 2 sql string I want to combine:

- The first table has all data of a product
- The second table (`inner join`) has all data of products that has a group price.

But I get different result

test search 'sku'

```
SELECT sku
FROM  `c3eiwitlive`.`catalog_product_entity` 
WHERE (
 `entity_id` LIKE  '%17086%'
)
```

Direct sql on the `group_price` table

result 269 records

```
SELECT SKU, value
FROM  `c3eiwitlive`.`catalog_product_entity_group_price` AS T1
INNER JOIN
`c3eiwitlive`.`catalog_product_entity` AS T2 
ON T1.`entity_id` = T2.`entity_id`;
```

Combined sql returns less records

result 234 records

```
SELECT name
FROM  `c3eiwitlive`.`catalog_product_flat_1` AS T1
WHERE T1.`sku` 
IN (
    SELECT sku
    FROM  `c3eiwitlive`.`catalog_product_entity_group_price` AS T1
    INNER JOIN  `c3eiwitlive`.`catalog_product_entity` AS T2 ON T1.`entity_id` = T2.`entity_id`
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It look to me like there are some sku entries missing from the 'catalog_product_flat_1' table.
Why not invert the query to identify the missing rows?

```
SELECT sku
FROM  `c3eiwitlive`.`catalog_product_entity_group_price` AS T1
INNER JOIN  `c3eiwitlive`.`catalog_product_entity` AS T2 ON T1.`entity_id` = T2.`entity_id`
WHERE sku 
NOT IN (
      SELECT sku from `c3eiwitlive`.`catalog_product_flat_1`
)
```